# Google Cloud - Local SSD hadware failure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are planning to use Google Cloud Local SSDs, because we need better IOPS than the persistent SSD disk have. We want to build a RAID5 array with 4 disks with mdamd (Linux). My question: how can we manage hardware failure with these disks? We can't unplug these disks, because we don't have phisycal access to the server. If we remove a disk with mdamd and add a new one, will it solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local SSD is an [ephemeral storage space and is not a reliable storage method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds). For example, should the machine hosting your VM suffer from a hardware failure, your data will be lost and unrecoverable. The same is true if you stop the machine on purpose or accidentally.

RAID does not help, as your instance (and Google for that matter) will lose access to the data you stored on Local SSD once the instance stops running on that machine.